# Getting Error: "Mutations" defined in resolvers, but not in schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-server

I am learning graphQL. Could somebody help me understand why Mutations are not being identified in Schema?

Getting this error:

```
 Error: "Mutations" defined in resolvers, but not in schema
```

Following is the code:

Schema:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
 type Author {
 age: String
 name: String
 books: [String]
}

type Query {
  authors: [Author]
  author(id: String): Author
}

type Mutation {
  addAuthor(name: String, age: Int, books: [String]): Author    
}  
`;

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });
export default schema;
```

Resolvers:

```
const resolvers = {
Query: {
    authors: () => {
        // return authors;
    },
    author: (root, { id }) => {
        // return authors.find(author => author.id === id);
    }
},

Mutations: {
    addAuthor: (root, {name, age, books}) => {
        const author = new authorModel({name, age, books});
        return author.save();
    }
  }
}

export default resolvers;
```

Answer (score 6):

As the error indicates, you don't have a type named `Mutations` in your schema. It's named `Mutation`. Any types and/or fields in your resolver map must match your schema exactly.